# Flash, Drag and select multiple characters in game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs4, flashdevelop

I am learning to make games in Flash. I know I should probably use HTML5 or other platforms but let it be like this. I will learn those stuff later..

**My question is like this, I want to select multiple characters in game. For example, I have 5 tanks. I want to drag-select them and move them to a point. How can I do that? Any mouseEvent or function for that? Moving them to a point is a different criteria I guess, but selecting a group of tanks. That's what I want to learn.
I am going to use Flixel game engine for this.**

PSST! ~ If you guys don't want to help me, step by step by giving me exact code. I am fine! Just guide me in the right path and I will learn it myself.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, do you know how to select one tank and move it where player clicked?
I'm not sure Is it an easy task for you. I'll give you some ideas about selection and how to detect it.

1. Bounds and Rectangles. Every tank has bounds represented as Rectangle, and by dragging your selection over tanks, you are forming also Rectangle. So you could check [intersection of these rectangles](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Rectangle.html#intersects%28%29)
2. If you don't want to work with bounds, but with ready to use display object methods. By dragging Rectangle selection, you could form transparent shape, and check if it [intersects with tanks](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestObject%28%29) This approach is slower than first.